# Qt static libraries undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, static-libraries

I have this situation:

- libA.a that has no dependencies
- libB.a that depends on libA.a
- libC.a that depends on libA.a

in B.pro i have

```
LIBS += -lA
```

in C.pro i have

```
LIBS += -lA
```

in app.pro i have

```
LIBS += -lA
LIBS += -lB
LIBS += -lC
```

But when i compile the linker gives me undefined references on libA classes that are used in libB and libC.

How can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: yes i am using QtCreator

Comment: I also had a similar problem and solved it by changing the order of the LIBS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIBS += -lA` are ignored in B.pro and C.pro. That option is applicable only for the linker, i.e. then a shared library or executable binary are built.

To resolve the issue with the undefined references reorder libs in app.pro. The order of dependent libraries does matter. See [The order in which interdependent linked libraries are specified is wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/6752050)

```
LIBS += -lB
LIBS += -lC
LIBS += -lA
```